# Need a specific section of a smart object warped

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: Example]

As displayed above, I need to warp one part of a smart object one way, and another part a different way.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the smart object and use masks on two layers rather than trying to do it all with one layer.

Answer (score 0):

No, if the shape is left as a Smart object, you must convert the shape to Raster to warp - although you can still transform the shape using 'handles'. If your shape/image needs 2 or more very distinct different treatments you might consider making multiple copies and applying the effects separately and splicing image together at the end.